# How to configure ExternalProject during main project configuration?

Tags: cmake, external-project

The CMake's [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/ExternalProject.html) allows to define how to an external project is going to be downloaded, configured, built and installed. All whose steps are going to be performed at the build time.

I would like to perform the configuration step of an external project during configuration of the main project. When the external project configuration is done the description of imported targets are available so the external project can be loaded with `find_package()` function.

Is it possible to build some targets at configuration time?

Comment: `ExternalProject` is just a sequence of steps. So you may use one `ExternalProject_Add()` call for being built at main project's *configuration stage* (e.g., as described in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553280/how-to-build-cmake-externalproject-while-configurating-main-one)), and second `ExternalProject_Add()`call for being build at main's project *build stage*. But I don't understand how *configured* project may be used via `find_package()`: normally this requires project to be *installed*.

Comment: The moment you run cmake configuration on the external project it outputs ExternalProjectConfig.cmake file that can be used by `find_package(... CONFIG)`.

Comment: Hm, yes, using `*Config.cmake` from *build* tree may work in some cases. But only *installed* variant of this file is garanteed to work: the file may include other `.cmake` files, which layout in *build* and *install* trees may differ.

Answer (score 13):

*ExternalProject* is just a sequence of steps to perform. So you may use **two instances** of it:

1. ExternalProject_Add() call to be built at main project's *configuration stage*. E.g., as described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553280/how-to-build-cmake-externalproject-while-configurating-main-one):

**other_project/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
project(other_project)
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(<project_name> <options...>
    BUILD_COMMAND "" # Disable build step.
    INSTALL_COMMAND "" # Disable install step too.
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# The first external project will be built at *configure stage*
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/other_project
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/other_project
)
```

2. ExternalProject_Add() call to be built at main project's *build stage*.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# The second external project will be built at *build stage*
ExternalProject_Add(<project_name> <options...>
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" # Disable configure step. But other steps will be generated.
)
```

By using same *<options>* for both `ExternalProject_Add()` calls we achieve "preemption" of both external projects created: build and follow steps of the second project will use result of configure step of the first one.

Comment: Just note that ``execute_process`` will not create its ``WORKING_DIRECTORY`` if it does not exist yet so before executing process you likely want to call ``file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/other_project)``. Not sure if it was case with older versions of CMake...

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment. I remember that I have checked that approach (for verify whether "preemption" of ExternalProject's works), but don't remember how I adjusted build directory for it. I will check that.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to *build* the project at configure-time<sup>†</sup>, but just want to download it, use [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html). `FetchContent_Declare` uses many of the same arguments as `ExternalProject_Add`, except it doesn't allow building the project.

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) has a great example on how to use this:

> ```
> FetchContent_Declare(
>   googletest
>   GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
>   GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
> )
>
> FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)
> if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
>   FetchContent_Populate(googletest)
>   add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} ${googletest_BINARY_DIR})
> endif()
> ```

This requires CMake 3.11 or later. For prior versions, you can download the [`FetchContent.cmake` module](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FetchContent.cmake) from the CMake repository along with the [FetchContent directory](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/tree/master/Modules/FetchContent), ensuring you comply with the BSD 3-Clause license.

<sup>† Building at configure-time has some serious drawbacks. For example, users of your library can't control the build process unless you set it up very carefully. A package manager is a better solution</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The [Hunter C++ package manager](https://hunter.readthedocs.io) does what I asked for. Hunter is based on CMake ExternalProject, but comes with a set of predefined projects. Also, it builds the dependencies **during configuration** and they can be accessed by `find_package(... CONFIG)`. Very nice stuff!

Comment: Could you add a short summary of how building at configuration time is implemented?

Answer (score 2):

Since CMake 3.14 and up wards, this how you use FetchContent

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
```

Then to build your test
`test/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(${PROJECT_NAME}_test)

# Tests for mu_project
file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_test ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_test gtest gmock_main)

# Register the tests
add_test(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_test
         COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}_test)
enable_testing()
```

You're now good to go

Comment: Is there a way to tell cmake not to import all targets from the external module? I' trying to use this method to include gRPC in my project but it fills my targets list with a bunch of garbage targets

Comment: Sorry but that, I just don't know. If I find something I will get back to you.