# Accessing include directories of a cmake project added as subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake

Consider a simple scenario where my cmake project adds a dependency as a subdirectory:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
├── include
│
└── externals
    └── BAR
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── src
        └── include
```

The main CMakeLists.txt is something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(FOO)

add_subdirectory(externals/BAR)

set(SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo.cpp
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/bar.hpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include                    # this works
    ${BAR_INCLUDE_DIR})                            # this does not
```

The problem is, the include directories of the added project are not accessable from FOO project.

BAR is a huge dependency with its own sub directories. Its root cmake uses `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` command (instead of `target_include_directories`). It then does some `FILE ( GLOB headers` and use them when triggering `make install`

I am aware that there are many questions regarding subdirectories in cmake, however, in my case cannot modify the CMakeLists.txt in the subdirectory. It's a git submodule that gets updated constantly and it's a pain to modify it constantly.

How can I access BAR's include directories (and later its libraries) without changing its cmake**s**?

P.S. BAR gets compiled properly and shared library appears in the build folder.

Comment: Did you try accessing `BAR_INCLUDE_DIR` from the top-level CMake? Is it empty? Is it not populated completely? When using `add_subdirectory()`, some of these `BAR_*` variables **should** be accessible...

Comment: @squareskittles, Thanks for feedback, my bad. I was looking at a standalone version of it **after** `make install`. The cmake itself makes `GLOB` to `headers` and then install them. The question then is, how can I access its headers if it doesn't set `BAR_INCLUDE_DIR` without installation?

Comment: You could've used `PARENT_SCOPE` to expose include dir from under subdirectory but since you say you can't modify subproject `CMakeLists.txt` I guess there's no other way

Comment: "The question then is, how can I access its headers if it doesn't set BAR_INCLUDE_DIR without installation?" - Install `BAR` first and only then configure your project. That way you may use `find_package(BAR)`. Alternative to pre-installation is installing the `BAR` during configuring your project, so futher `find_package(BAR)` will work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks. I'm more for your second suggestion. Does it mean by some hand made bash magic or there are some already existing mechanism in cmake? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You may use [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) for run scripts or tools immediately at configuration stage. Alternatively, the function [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) easily drives building an external project. While the function itself  builds the external project only at the *build* stage of the main project, there are approaches to change that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845413/how-to-configure-externalproject-during-main-project-configuration.