# CMake: FetchContent interferes with CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: cmake

So I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    some_software
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/some_company/some_software
    GIT_TAG master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(some_software)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${some_software_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain.cmake")

project(my_software)

message("CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
message("CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
message("CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

...
```

in which I first want to download and install some 3rd party library and then set the toolchain file to some `toolchain.cmake` file in the directory of the 3rd party library because I require cross-compiler tools.

For some reason, however, the `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ...)` after the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(some_software)` is ignored. Actually, the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable points to the correct `toolchain.cmake` file, but the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variables are not updated to the cross-compiler tools (when `project(my_software)` is called) but instead point to the standard tools. The `message(...)`s in the `toolchain.cmake` file are also not printed, as if the `toolchain.cmake` file is completely ignored by CMake.

When I remove the `FetchContent`, "manually" download the 3rd party library, and set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to the manually downloaded copy of the 3rd party library with `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/path/to/toolchain.cmake")` everything works as expected.

The interesting part is, that I can actually keep the `FetchContent` as long as I set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` before the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(some_software)` with `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/path/to/toolchain.cmake")`. Everything works just fine then. But obviously, this is not practical, as the `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${some_software_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain.cmake")` relies on the `some_software_SOURCE_DIR` variable which is only available after `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(some_software)`.

It seems as if CMake is ignoring the `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ...)` or more specifically is not updating its internal tool variables once `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(some_software)` has been executed. How can I "force" CMake to update its tool variables?

Thanks in advance!

`Ubuntu 18.04`
`cmake version 3.21.1`

EDIT: I basically just want to download some 3rd party library at configure time so that the content is available immediately, e.g. the `toolchain.cmake` file. This appears to only be possible with [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html). However, as pointed out by Tsyvarev, with FetchContent, the 3rd party library becomes part of my project, and I am forced to use the same tools for both, as a single CMake project may use only a single compiler. [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) could help here, but the problem is that it does not provide its contents at configure time, making it impractical for my purpose.

Comment: "I first want to download and install some 3rd party library and then set the toolchain file ..." - This is impossible to achieve by using `FetchContent`. All projects, included via `FetchContent`, become **part of your project**. During configuration and building, a single CMake project may use only the single compiler. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168094/cmake-how-to-change-compiler-for-individual-target). For build some project with distinct complier, you could use `ExternalProject`, which configures and builds **separate** CMake project.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I will give `ExternalProject` a try and report back. Thank you! As far as I can see `ExternalProject` only gets "evaluated" at build time. But I already need the `toolchain.cmake` when running CMake? This is why chose `FetchContent`.

Comment: The only other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845413/how-to-configure-externalproject-during-main-project-configuration) I found seems cumbersome as well.

Comment: For building other project you could use `execute_process`. Like with `FetchContent` approach, such project will be immediately available, but you are not restricted in toolchain when building it. (But like with `ExternalProject` approach, CMake variables and targets provided by such project are not available for the main project.)