# Smart way to CMake a project using pybind11 by ExternalProject_Add

Tags: cmake, pybind11

I'm writing a python module using `pybind11` with `CMake` 3.9.4.
As it is convenience, I wish to download `pybind11` source files using `ExternalProject_Add` in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

When I run `cmake .`, it does not download `pybind11` source files,  and throws an error.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory
    /Users/me/foo/pybind11_external-prefix/src/pybind11_external
  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (pybind11_add_module):
  Unknown CMake command "pybind11_add_module".
```

There is a workaround:

1. comment out the last 3 lines in CMakeLists.txt
2. run `cmake .`
3. run `make` (then, it downloads `pybind11` source files)
4. restore the last 3 lines in CMakeLists.txt
5. run `cmake .`
6. run `make`

However, this is not smart... Is there any way to download `pybind11` using `ExternalProject_Add` without commenting the lines out and restoring them (and without running `cmake` and `make` twice)?

**/Users/me/foo/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(foo)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
        pybind11_external
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git
        GIT_TAG v2.2.1
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD -std=c++14)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(pybind11_external source_dir)
include_directories(${source_dir}/include)

add_subdirectory(${source_dir})             # comment out, then restore this line
pybind11_add_module(foo SHARED foo.cpp)     # comment out, then restore this line
add_dependencies(foo pybind11_external)     # comment out, then restore this line
```

**/Users/me/foo/foo.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_LIBRARY_H
#define FOO_LIBRARY_H

#include<pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j);

#endif
```

**/Users/me/foo/foo.cpp**

```cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that ExternalProject is built only at *build stage* of the main project. So `add_subdirectory()` into ExternalProject isn't work, because it is processed at *configuration stage*. [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553280/how-to-build-cmake-externalproject-while-configurating-main-one) describes building ExternalProject at configuration stage.

Answer (score 20):

With CMake's [FetchContent](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/projects/fetch.html) module (version 3.11+), you can do this:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    pybind11
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pybind/pybind11
    GIT_TAG        v2.2.3
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(pybind11)
if(NOT pybind11_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(pybind11)
    add_subdirectory(${pybind11_SOURCE_DIR} ${pybind11_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
```

This will download pybind11 at configure time, and `add_subdirectory` it. Then you're ready to call `pybind11_add_module`.