# Build non-cmake 3rd party library and use pkg-config to get the library info needed for building the main project

Tags: cmake, dpdk, pkg-config, meson-build

I've a CMake project which depends on a 3rd party library - DPDK in this case.
The DPDK library is build via Meson and then the include dirs, the CFLAGS, the LDFLAGS, etc. can/should be get via pkg-config.
Note that I don't want to use the system installed DPDK because I need some features from the latest version. I also would like to not install the built DPDK library in the system paths but keep it in the project structure.
I used [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add) to "build" the DPDK and this worked fine.
However, I couldn't use [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules) because it causes the pkg-config to be invoked at the configure time while I need it to happen at build time and after the build of the DPDK library.
So, I was wondering what are my options to do the following:

- make the pkg-config call dependent on the build of the DPDK library
- set CMake variables from the pkg-config call so that I can use them for the build of the main project.

I guess, I could use `ExternalProject_Add_Step` but don't see an option to set CMake environment variables from there.

Comment: If you are building your DPDK library from source, perhaps the solution is to add it as a submodule to your project?

Comment: Do you mean github submodule? I'll see if I can change the whole setup in this way and overcome the current problems.

Comment: I mean add it as Git submodule and than add this to your project with CMake add_subdirectory command.

Comment: pkg-config will be useless for you, since you don't want to use system-wide version of the lib, but want to build it from source each time. So I think the soultion will be what I've mentioned

Comment: It seems to me that add_subdirectory can be used for CMake projects where CMakeLists.txt is available in the source directory. While DPDK is built with Meson and after the build it produces the .pc files for the pkg-config.

Comment: pkg-config needs to be used because the linking to the static DPDK libraries is not trivial. They need to be given in particular order, the build flags for the DPDK (march, etc) need to be used for the main project too. pkg-config makes this things trivial and it's intended way for using DPDK. 
I'm currently using DPDK in this way, as 3rd party library but I build the main project with Make. For the next project I'd like to use CMake if possible.

Comment: CMake requires all compiler/linker flags to be specified at **configuration stage**, but ExternalProject defers building the subproject to the **building stage**. I know no package manager which will be able to get information about a project (flags and libraries to be build against that project) when the project is not built yet. You may want to build the external project at the configuration stage instead, see e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553280/how-to-build-cmake-externalproject-while-configurating-main-one).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for the idea. I'd mark this as an accepted answer but don't know how because it's a comment.